# Emacs 24.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, gdb within emacs window switching all broke up

Tags: c++, c, debugging, emacs, gdb

This used to work really well. I loved it. I showed everyone how cool it was. Now it's broke.

```
M-X gdb, 
gdb -i=mi MYPROGRAMNAME, 
set args, 
run, 
screen splits to show output, 
C-X o to output screen, 
C-X b to get to gdb commandline
```

BOOM, error message

**Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window.**

I don't need the program output at this point and rarely do. I need to control gdb and see the source code but now I cannot use the program output screen to control gdb because it's a "dedicated window?". I have to split the program output screen into two tiny windows. Very sad. I need a drink.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x gud-gdb` instead of `M-x gdb`.  But it has drawbacks, e.g. you can't set breakpoints by clicking in the fringe.  On the plus side, you can have several debugging sessions running in parallel.

Comment: Now that's what I'm used to. Thanks. Works like a charm.